# Triple booting Ubuntu mate, Windows 10, and CloudReady (chromium os)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, ubuntu-mate, chromeos

Is it possible to do this? I don’t care about reformatting, as this laptop has nothing important on it.

Answer (score 0):

Win 10 and Ubuntu can be done, but windows might give problems for booting Ubuntu after window update/upgrade.  A fast google search turns up cloudready might be iffy to dual/triple boot.  You will need to do more research to see if you want to do this.